# Can't insert records into SQL Server Tables from Access

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

I created a pair of Access (365) files. One is a front-end with forms, the other is all tables. I then migrated the tables over to SQL Server (2008 R2) on a remote machine. I got the front-end to talk to the SQL server instance using an ODBC connection. I have several screens which work on the tables, some are bound to the tables, some are unbound.

I can update data in existing records and I can remove records, but I can't insert any. This is happening on both bound and unbound forms. I saw posts that said I needed to:

-Set a default of ((0)) for all BINARY fields and set so that they can accept blanks,

-Change all NVarchar() fields to Varchar() fields, and

-make sure every table has a timestamp field.

I did all of those, but no luck. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Oh, yeah, I also made sure every table has a key.

Comment: What does "can't" mean? Do you get an error message? Could you share it?

Comment: No error message. I fill out the form, close the form, look into the table, no new record. But if I modify an existing record, I can see the changes...

Comment: If you open a linked table, can you add records that way?

Comment: Why don't you use Migration tool? http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=43690

Comment: as @AlbertD.Kallal said, check if you can add records via table. Check if you use transactions (commit), check if any error raises me.undo and a silly one is your form bounded to correct table? :)

Comment: Yes, if I open a linked table, I can add records that way. Since UPDATEs do indeed update the correct tables, I'll conclude that I'm bound to the correct table. :-)

Comment: King_Fisher, I used the SQL Sever Import and Export Wizard. Any reason to believe that that tool would produce different results than the Migration tool? (Or, are they really the same thing?) Thanks, everyone, I appreciate the comments!

Comment: Krish KM, no I'm not using "commit"s. I do have some forms bound to queries, rather than directly to tables, but I don't see that making a difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! The field was specified as a Primary Key, but its 'Identity' property was set to 'no'. Changing that fixed the problem...Thanks again, all!